# how to install sublime into nixos?

Tags: sublimetext2, nixos, nix

I found that there is support for sublime for nixos : https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/applications/editors/sublime/default.nix .

I cannot figure it out how to install it though.

I was following these instructions without success : https://nixos.org/wiki/Nix_Installing_Packages

I also tried this :

```
git remote add channels git://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs-channels.git
```

but it did not help.

Answer (score 5):

### Using `nix` without NixOS

`cat ~/.nixpkgs/config.nix`

```
{
    allowUnfree = true;
}
```

`nix-env -i sublime`

### On NixOS

`cat /etc/nixos/configuration.nix`

```
...
{ config, pkgs, ... }:
{
  # ...
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    sublime
  ];
  nixpkgs.config = {
      allowUnfree = true;
  };
}
```

`sudo nixos-rebuild switch --upgrade`

Comment: The question is tagged `sublimetext2` - I think this installs the wrong version?

Comment: indeed fixed for nixos

Comment: Note that on nixos if you use your non-root user to search for packages like `nix-env -qaP package`, then you need to add the `allowUnfree=true` option to your non-root user's config.nix, even if this option is also specified in the system `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` file.

Comment: This worked for me on NixOS 16.03. I wanted SublimeText 3 so I changed "sublime" above in the `systemPackages` section to `sublime3` and then did `nixos-rebuild switch --upgrade` and it's installed.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have done this.

```
$ nix-channel --add http://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable
$ nix-channel --update
```

or just

`nix-env --install sublime`

and please let me if it works? if it doesn't 
then I have tried searching here https://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html

I'm not able to find sublime there.

I would suggest you follow [this](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started/install.html#other-linux-distributions) to install sublime.

Comment: even this also not working? `nix-env --install hello`

Comment: I read this : `Note: On NixOS, you’re automatically subscribed to a NixOS channel corresponding to your NixOS major release (e.g. http://nixos.org/channels/nixos-14.12). A NixOS channel is identical to the Nixpkgs channel, except that it contains only Linux binaries and is updated only if a set of regression tests succeed.` here : http://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ch-basic-package-mgmt ; might this be the problem ?

Comment: @jhegedus have you tired query `nix-env --query --available`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78590/discussion-between-vaibhav-mule-and-jhegedus).

Comment: thank you for the help so far, I think I give up on solving this problem for now, too little time...